# WebSQL alternative for mobile web apps?

Tags: iphone, android, web-sql

Let me clarify, when I say mobile web apps I mean web apps that are designed to run across different mobile platforms, not native mobile apps that access the internet for data.

So I was doing some reading to see how these mobile web apps could store data on the client side. According to the book:

Building Andriod Apps with html, css, and javascript by Jonathan Stark

same book but with different title

Building iPhone Apps with html, css, and javascript by Jonathan Stark

He discussed using WebSQL which is not no longer part of the html5 spec. So I was wondering what is the alternative to WebSQL to storing data using a database for offline usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IndexedDB is supposed to be the standard going forward, but sadly it appears that it's currently only supported by desktop browsers. (FF > 4.0 & Chrome > 11)

In the meantime, your options for Android/IOS are to use WebSQL or LocalStorage. Just keep in mind that with local storage you're limited to a very small amount of data storage so at the moment your options are somewhat limited.

Comment: Is there no javascript hack per se?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Indexed Database API is the new suggestion http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_Database_API